# Finding extreme point of a set determined by two planes in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, 3d

Problem asks to find a extreme point the set $\{(x,y,z) \mid x-2y \leq 3 , 2y+3z \geq 4 \}$. But I don't think it has a extreme point, because it is intersection of two hyper planes in 3D, which doesn't look like has a extreme point at all. Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: You're right. The set is just a "wedge" enclosed by two planes. Any point on the line of intersection of the two planes is an extreme point, I think.

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying. How can be a point on the line of intersection be extreme point ?

Comment: It's possible that I mis-remembered the definition of "extreme point". If the points on the line are not extreme points, then there aren't any.

Answer (score 1):

You are right; the intersection of two closed half-spaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ does not have any extreme points. Indeed, let $u,v$ be the normal vectors of these halfspaces. Let $w=u\times v$. The vector $w$ is parallel to the boundary of either halfspace. Hence, for any point $p$ in the intersection, the points $p\pm w$ are also there.